# Graylog spawning a lot of child processes

Tags: java, graylog2, graylog

We have a Graylog 2.0.2 (4da1379) setup which collects a very small amount of data (avg of 0 msg per minute), our sysadmin is complaining it's eating a lot of memory and it seems Graylog is spawning 170 child processes which are hogging memory.

Is it the expected behavior for Graylog to be spawning such a large amount of child processes? I went through the docs but couldn't find anything, however the threaddump available via the webinterface did have a large amount of threads in the 'waiting' status, e.g.

```
web-worker-15 id=236 state=WAITING
```

So is there something wrong with the setup, can we configure the number of threads somehow or should we just add more memory?

Comment: You should probably report this (with some more details) to the project at https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues

Comment: Was thinking about doing so, but wasn't sure if this was expected behavior or not. But given your familiarity with the project, I should indeed report it :) I'll open an issue and post the link here, thanks for the reply!

Comment: done: https://github.com/Graylog2/graylog2-server/issues/2363